# Receiving a KeyError: '0_0' for my python program

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, data-structures

I'm was working on this question (it's from Leetcode):

> "Given an integer matrix, find the length of the longest increasing
>   path.
>
> From each cell, you can either move to four directions: left, right, up or down. 
>   You may NOT move diagonally or move outside of the
>   boundary (i.e. wrap-around is not allowed).
>
> ```
> Example 1:
>
> nums = [
>   [9,9,4],
>   [6,6,8],
>   [2,1,1]
> ]
> Return 4.
> ```

I keep running into a KeyError specifically:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/longest_increasing_path_in_a_matrix.py", line 41, in <module>
    print(test.longestIncreasingPath(matrix))
  File "/Users/Desktop/longest_increasing_path_in_a_matrix.py", line 31, in longestIncreasingPath
    traverse(x, y, [])
  File "/Users/Desktop/longest_increasing_path_in_a_matrix.py", line 5, in traverse
    if traverse.traveled[str(x_coor) + "_" + str(y_coor)]:
KeyError: '0_0'
```

and I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong. I understand it has to do with my dictionary. Please let me know if there is anything else I need to post:

```
class Solution(object):
def longestIncreasingPath(self, matrix):

    def traverse(x_coor, y_coor, build):
        key = str(x_coor) + "_" + str(y_coor)
        if key in traverse.traveled and traverse.traveled[key]:
            if traveled[str(x_coor) + "_" + str(y_coor)]:
                return
            elif x_coor < 0 or y_coor < 0 or x_coor >= len(matrix[0]) or y_coor >= len(matrix)-1:
                return
            elif len(build) > 0 and matrix[x_coor][y_coor] <= build[-1]:
                if len(build) > traverse.count:
                    traverse.count = len(build)
                return 

            traveled[str(x_coor) + "_" + str(y_coor)] = true
            build.append(matrix[y_coor][x_coor])
            traverse(x_coor, y_coor-1, build)
            traverse(x_coor, y_coor+1, build)
            traverse(x_coor+1, y_coor, build)
            traverse(x_coor-1, y_coor, build)
            build.pop()
            del traveled[str(x_coor) + "_" + str(y_coor)]

        traverse.count = 0
        traverse.traveled = {}


        for y in range(0, len(matrix)-1, 1):
            for x in range(0, len(matrix[0]), 1):
                traverse(x, y, [])

        return(traverse.count)
matrix = [
    [9,9,4],
    [6,6,8],
    [2,1,1]
]
test = Solution()
print(test.longestIncreasingPath(matrix))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a key (`0_0`) that doesn't exist yet in the dictionary.

You have to check beforehand if it exists, I'd suggest the `in` keyword:

```
key = str(x_coor) + "_" + str(y_coor)
if key in traverse.traveled and traverse.traveled[key]:
    # ...
```

Comment: Another option might be `if traverse.traveled.get(key)`. The `get` method returns `None` (by default) if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary.

Comment: Updated: added link to documentation that details other methods for avoiding such errors

Comment: Come on, just look it up, that's a pretty common error you got there... Even the error itself is pretty explicit

Comment: Actually, the inconsistent tabs error ended up causing another issue (ended  up being a train of errors). When I compile everything, I seem to get 'None' as the output. Not sure if anyone can spot what I've done wrong

Comment: You should mark this question as answered and post another question since this isn't quite the same problem. Hint, you should add lots of prints to debug what path your program follows. Also, remind yourself indentation in Python controls the scopes (e.g. start and end of functions). Ask yourself where are your `traverse` function is defined and where it is called. Once you got it all figured out, if you still have a problem that you can't solve by looking on the internet, feel free to open another question.